# Replacing string and characters in front of it in Python

Tags: python

I need to write a python program to fix links in a text file.

Every

```
/00/o/1.jpg
```

where `00` is a random 2-digit, should be changed to

```
/1.jpg
```

The code I have now is

```
with open("new.txt", "wt") as out:
    for line in open("source.txt"):
        out.write(line.replace('/o/', ''))
```

but this code won't do anything about the `/00` in front of `/o/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just split at the furthest forward slash?

```
with open("new.txt", "wt") as out:
    for line in open("source.txt"):
        out.write('/' + line.rsplit('/', 1)[1])
```

Comment: this works very well! Thank you very much. As for other answers, sorry, I forgot to mention that this is for hyperlinks.

Comment: How about if I want to change "http://www.stackoverflow.com/00/o/1.jpg" to "http://www.stackoverflow.com/1.jpg"?

Comment: @user2790942 Hmm, you'd probably want to use a regular expression: `s = "stackoverflow.com/00/o/1.jpg"` `'/'.join(re.findall(r'^(.*?)/\w{2}/o/(.*)$', s)[0])`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
>>> import os
>>> strs = "/00/o/1.jpg"
>>> '/' + os.path.split(strs)[-1]
'/1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> '/' + os.path.basename('/00/o/1.jpg')
'/1.jpg'
```